# Which of the following facts are true of a sequence satisfying $\lim a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers such that
>
> $$\lim a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$
>
> Which of the following are correct?
>
> - $\sum a_n$ converges
> - $\sum a_nx^n$ converges uniformly on $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$
> - $\sum a_nx^n$ converges uniformly on $[-1,1]$
> - $\lim \sup\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$

**My effort**:

1.false ,consider $a_n=n$

2.true,The radius of convergence of  a power series $\frac{1}{R}=\lim a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1\implies R=1$ .Hence the series converges uniformly for compact sets inside $|x|<1$.Hence the series converges uniformly in $|x|\leq 0.5$

3.false ,putting $x=1$ the same as in case 1.

4.I am unable to prove this fact.How to solve this .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, way to go for your efforts. As far as I can see, your answers to the first three questions are correct. To refute the last one consider the sequence

$$\{a_n\}=\{1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,....\}=\begin{cases}k,&n=2k-1\\{}\\1,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Observe that

$$\left\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\}=\left\{1,2,\frac12,3,\frac13,4,...\right\}$$

Comment: in order to show that $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ should i do like this:::. if $n=$ odd then $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ and if $n=$ even then $a_n=1\forall n$ hence $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

Comment: is it okay ;please comment

Comment: Yes, it is right. If you can split a sequence in a finite set of pairwise disjoint subsequences such that each such subsequence converges *to the same limit*, then the whole sequence converges to the same common limit.

Comment: If you don't mind,can I ask you for a outline of the proof ;I have heard of the result that if every subsequence converges to the same limit then the  original sequence converges.But this result is new

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya If $n$ is odd, $a_n^{1/n}\ne1$.

Comment: Why @Did; if $n=$ odd then $a_n=k$ and $\lim a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$;please correct me if wrong

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya Well, because [$a_n^{1/n}=1$] and [$\lim a_n^{1/n}=1$] are not the same mathematical statement, are they?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer to 2) is wrong. $R=1$ implies the power series converges absolutely for $|x|<1,$ but not uniformly in that range. Example: $\sum x^n.$ However, the power series will converge uniformly in $[-a,a]$ for all $a\in [0,1).$

Comment: But the example you give *does converge uniformly* on $\;[-1/2,\,1/2]\;$ , which is what is being asked in (2).

Comment: But the reason given by the OP was that the series converges uniformly on $(-1,1).$ That reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: I think that reasoning is correct: if the power series $\;\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n\;$ has convergence radius $\;R\;$, then for *any* $\;z\,,\,\,|z-z_0|<R\;$ the convergence is absolute, and it is uniform on any compact subset contained in the circle (interval, in the real case) of convergence.

Comment: Did you even read the OP's answer 2)?

Comment: @S. I think I can see zhw's point now and he's right: you wrote at the end of your reasoning in point (2) that the series converges unif. for $\;|z|<1\;$ . This is false.

Comment: thanks ;i have corrected my answer ;please check

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya Now it looks fine. Had I written that exam I could have expected this, I guess...yet I missed when I first read it. Never mind, I would have given most of the points to that answer.

Comment: Of course, @zhw.'s answer deserves an upvote. +1

Answer (score 0):

For the last one , a general result can help you :
$$\lim\sup\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{{a_n}}\right|\ge \lim\sup|a_n|^{1/n}$$
$$ \lim\inf|a_n|^{1/n}\ge\lim\inf \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{{a_n}}\right|$$